# Creating a two-level hierarchy in LINQ

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two tables in SQL:

```
DOCUMENT
ID int
Description varchar(50)

DOCUMENTLINK
ParentID int
ChildID int
```

How do I return the hierarchy (only two levels are used) formed by these two tables as an object using LINQ?

The structure would be something like:

```
Parent1  
---------Child1  
---------Child2  
Parent2  
---------Child3  
Parent3  
Parent4  
---------Child2  
---------Child3  
Parent5  
---------Child1  
---------Child4
---------Child5
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you using Linq-to-objects or Linq-to-SQL?

Comment: @callisto Don't add tags in the title. That's what the tags section is used for ;)

Comment: The title indicates you want to do this in SQL, the question says LINQ.  The tags say both.  Very confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ answer:

```
var tree = from top in nodes
           from middle in nodes
           from bottom in nodes
           where top.Id == middle.ParentId
           && middle.Id == bottom.Id
           select new
           {
               Top = top,
               Middle = middle,
               Bottom = bottom
           };
```

Comment: Thank you! I am definitely using this way, as it works for the most part. How would I group by the top object?

Comment: I'd do it entirely different with grouping.  You could use group by on these results, but you could just skip the effort to put it in a flat list to begin with.

Comment: from top in nodes select new { Top = top, Children = (from middle in nodes where top.Id == middle.ParentId select new {Middle = middle, Children = ( from bottom in nodes....

Answer (score 1):

The SQL answer is:

```
SELECT *
FROM (Table1
INNER JOIN Table1 AS Table1_1 ON Table1.ParentID = Table1_1.ID)
INNER JOIN Table1 AS Table1_2 ON Table1_1.ParentID = Table1_2.ID;
```

Note, this will only show items that have all levels.  To get childless parents included, change all the inner joins to left outer joins